# TextView setText doesn't work under WAKE_LOCK-ED Activity

Tags: android, textview, settext

I have an alarm that sets off after a certain time using an activity. This Activity shows up under WAKE_LOCK function. Now, I want the activity to display information of the alarm. I use TextViews to display the information inside the onCreate of the Activity. And for some reason this test code doesn't work.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen);

    TextView tvName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.alarm_screen_name);
    tvName.setText("123");


    Button dismissButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reminderDismiss);

    dismissButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            finish();
        }
    });
    //Ensure wakelock release
    Runnable releaseWakelock = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
            getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
            getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
            getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);

            if (mWakeLock != null && mWakeLock.isHeld()) {
                mWakeLock.release();
                finish();
            }
        }
    };
    new Handler().postDelayed(releaseWakelock, WAKELOCK_TIMEOUT);
}
```

Do you guys have any idea why it's not working?

activity_screen XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center"
tools:context="com.example.ScreenActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/alarm_screen_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    android:text="Alarm!"
    android:textSize="38dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/alarm_screen_time"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    android:text="00 : 00"
    android:textSize="52dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/alarm_screen_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    android:text="Alarm name" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/reminderDismiss"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="106dp"
    android:text="Dismiss"
    android:onClick="dismiss"
    android:textSize="38dp" />
```

The Activity Shows up From this WAKE_LOCK:

```
public class AlarmService extends Activity {
private PowerManager.WakeLock mWakeLock;



public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstateState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstateState);

    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "My Wake Log");
    mWakeLock.acquire();
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen);


    //stop alarm
    Button stopAlarm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reminderDismiss);
    stopAlarm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });

}
}
```

And the service activates under this button from another activity:

```
public void saveAlarm(View v) {

    //set time into calendar instance
    GregorianCalendar calendar= new GregorianCalendar();
    calendar.set(GregorianCalendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,reminderHour);
    calendar.set(GregorianCalendar.MINUTE,reminderMinute);
    calendar.set(GregorianCalendar.SECOND,00);
    calendar.set(GregorianCalendar.MILLISECOND,0000);

    AlarmManager reminder = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    Intent reminderintent = new Intent(this, AlarmService.class);

    PendingIntent operation = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), 1, reminderintent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    reminder.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), operation);

    finish();
}
```

Comment: I believe there is no logcat error. The app works fine. It's just the textview text doesnt change. it feels like they ignored these lines of codes.

Comment: this code is not enough to determine the problem.post releveant code/layout to reproduce problem or if any error is encountered then post logcat.

Comment: "it feels like they ignored these lines of codes" have you tried using debugger on these lines?

Comment: better show `activity_screen` XML

Comment: What other code is needed? I'm still hard coded the textview settext. I dont think I need more code to show yet

Comment: Post the code on this layout R.layout.activity_screen

Comment: I think textview s are overlapping put them in LineaLayout

Comment: @sadeghsaati I don't think that will solve the problem

Comment: Seeking more clarity: Does `alarm_screen_name` still appear as "Alarm name" after the code is run? and do you have `onResume()` as well? Also, you need not use + when referring to an already created id in layout xml.

Comment: I have this logcat error when trying to debug. I don't think it's related. "java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long: "Service""

Comment: This code is not enough , post the rest of the code too

Comment: I was inserting your code into my eclipse and also checked into my mobile it is working.I am not facing any exception so it may be your different issue rather than TextView.

Comment: @Gagan yes. alarm name still appear as alarm name. and I don't have onResume() yet. I don't understand the + part. I need to use @+id/... to create an id.

Comment: I just replaced my XML.

Comment: @BhavinShah yeah. im pretty sure it's supposed to work. I am guessing it has something to do with the fact that this activity shows up under wakelock function. But I don't think it's supposed to be the problem.

Comment: When i clicked on your dismiss button then it crashed due to in your xml file you declared onClick but in java file OnClick method is not there so you declare onClick method for button click.May be you are facing this kind of problem.

Comment: @BhavinShah no. the button is fine. I have a seperate button function I use. check out the updated onCreate.

Answer (score 0):

it worked fine for me checkout the screenshot here [image]

and the code I wrote is same as you see here

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  {
    TextView tvText;
       @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         tvText=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.alarm_screen_name);
         tvText.setText("123");

    }

      }
```

Comment: Yes. I am also expecting it to work. But it doesn't. I am guessing it has to do with the fact that this activity shows up under WAKE_LOCK function. But I don't think it should be a problem

Comment: if you post your more code it will be easy for us to identify the mistake other wise no use discussion.

Comment: I added a bunch of codes. please check. I hope thats enough